# Python precision handling

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, rsa, precision

I just wonder why these 2 prints do not have the same output. I want to calculate Eulers Totient Func. 
For the future it would be cool if someone can tell me how python handle big numbers (60+ Digits) and how to operate with them.

Thank you

```
import math
a = (math.pow(19,6)-math.pow(19,5))
b = (math.pow(53,4)-math.pow(53,3))
c = (36)
d = (math.pow(101,3)-math.pow(101,2))
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(d)
y= int(a)*int(d)*int(c)*int(b)
print(int(y))
print(int(a*b*c*d))
```

The Output is:

```
44569782.0
7741604.0
36
1020100.0
12671169797620641340800
12671169797620641038336
```

Comment: Python *integers* can be arbitrarily big. *Floating-point numbers*, on the other hand, have 53 binary digits of precision, or about 17/18 decimal digits (on standard hardware). Nowhere in the region of the 60 you want. Look at the module `mpmath`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this is due to floating point error on large numbers. Use the built-in `pow` or `**` operator instead of `math.pow` for integers. Because `pow` and `**` return integers, explicitly casting to integers is unnecessary. Also, parentheses around variables is unneeded and reduces readability:

```
a = 19 ** 6 - 19 ** 5
b = 53 ** 4 - 53 ** 3
c = 36
d = 101 ** 3 - 101 ** 2
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(d)
y = a * b * c * d
print(y)
print(int(a * b * c * d))
```

---

```
44569782
7741604
36
1020100
12671169797620641340800
12671169797620641340800
```

Comment: I would mention that casting to int in that case is simply unecessary